# Very Confusing PDO php exec() connection issue

Tags: php, pdo, exec

I have run into a very confusing issue with connecting to a database via PHP PDO using exec().

I have thrown together the following snippet to illustrate my point.

```
$host = "localhost";
$db_name = "some_db";
$user_name = "some_user";
$pass_word = "some_password";

try {
// assign PDO object to db variable
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8", $user_name, $pass_word, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
echo "yahoo connected";
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
//Output error - would normally log this to error file rather than output to user.
echo "Connection Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

When I run this code via the browser it connects fine but when I run it at the command line it  gives the following error:

```
Connection Error: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'some_user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Needless to say that this is confusing as the password is indeed set as you can see in the code above and the connection works and prints yahoo to the screen in the browser. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Is it some_user your real database login user?

Comment: no, not at all. I would not put that on SO for security reasons. I just edited it for the question.

Comment: did you change the error too? Access denied for user 'some_user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: indeed I did, I just removed the real username and put in some_user for the sake of completeness. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your snippet is wrong. It ought to be without useless try-catch block:

```
$host = "localhost";
$db_name = "some_db";
$user_name = "some_user";
$pass_word = "some_password";


$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8"
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
    // other options 
);
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user_name, $pass_word, $opt);
echo "yahoo connected";
```

this way you will get a *complete* error message,including **stack trace** which will show you the **actual** file you runs - in which there is empty password used.

it is also important to have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to tell you possible issues with variables scope

Comment: OK, I have done this and managed to get it to connect to the database. My final issue seems to be with IIS. If I run the command at the server cmd then its fine. But if I run try running it through the browser using exec() then it fails, just does nothing